# Default Swift protocol implementation in extension for class that conforms to other protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

I have a class where some subclasses conform to Protocol1.  The API from Protocol1 is sufficient to implement Protocol2.  I want to do something like below, where I can define a default implementation of Protocol2 when an instance of my class conforms to Protocol1.  My first attempt looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {}

public protocol Protocol1 {
  var someProperty: Any { get }
}

public protocol Protocol2 {
  var func someFunc()
}

extension Protocol2 where Self: MyClass & Protocol1 {
  public func someFunc() {
    // Functionality that uses `.someProperty`
  } 
}
```

This compiles fine, so I thought it would work.  However I tried testing with something like:

```
public class MySubclass: MyClass {}
extension MySubclass: Protocol1 {
  public var someProperty: Any {
    // Return property value.
  }
}

let instance = MySubclass()
instance.someFunc()  // Throws compilation error
```

Unfortunately, I get a `Value of type 'MySubclass' has no member 'someFunc'` compilation error when attempting to call the function from Protocol2.  Is there a way to define a default implementation of Protocol2 for MyClass subclasses conforming to Protocol1, or would I just need to extend each subclass individually?

Comment: Does `MyClass` conform to  the `Protocol2` that you created?

Comment: ```MyClass``` doesn't conform to Protocol1, but ```MySubclass``` explicitly conforms to Protocol1.  I would think that Protocol2 conformance would be implicitly implemented by the extension, but no luck.

Comment: Why do you say that `MySubclass` would implicitly conform to `Protocol2`?

Comment: When you add a default implementation in a protocol extension it becomes the default implementation for any type that conforms to _Protocol2_, that you also add other requirements on that extension using a `where` will not change that. So you must read the `where` as an AND condition.

Comment: Yep you're right Joakim, thanks!  You need both, but the extension declaring conformance to Protocol2 doesn't need any functionality if the default has been implemented already.  I note this in my answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out actually.  You can define the default implementation with the where clause, but you still need to explicitly conform to Protocol2.  I have several MyClass subclasses conforming to Protocol1, so I didn't want to duplicate the implementations, but just adding explicit protocol conformance to Protocol2 with an empty definition block works:

```
extension Protocol2 where Self: MyClass & Protocol1 {
  public func someFunc() {
    // Functionality that uses `.someProperty`
  } 
}

public class MySubclass: MyClass {}
extension MySubclass: Protocol1 {
  public var someProperty: Any {
    // Return property value.
  }
}
extension MySubclass: Protocol2 {}

MySubclass().someFunc() // Works fine
```